# core plot x axis labels vertical

Tags: xcode, core-plot

I have a very crowded xy graph and I'm trying to display the x-axis labels vertically instead of the default horizontal. I can't find documentation on how to do this.  Can anyone explain how to do this or point me to the right documentation? I have adjusted the x.labelrotation but it does rotate the x axis label
thanks.

```
   #pragma mark - Chart behavior
-(void)initPlotThree {
    [self configureHostThree];
    [self configureGraphThree];
    [self configurePlotsThree];
    [self configureAxesThree];
}

-(void)configureHostThree {
    self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.myViewThree addSubview:self.hostView];
    CPTGraphHostingView *BarGraphView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] init];
    self.hostView.frame = CGRectMake(self.myViewThree.bounds.origin.x, self.myViewThree.bounds.origin.y, self.myViewThree.bounds.size.width, self.myViewThree.bounds.size.height);
    [self.hostView addSubview:BarGraphView];
}

-(void)configureGraphThree {
    // 1 - Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
    //        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme]];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];
    self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

    // 2 - Set graph title
    NSString *title = @"Tremor";
    graph.title = title;

    // 3 - Create and set text style
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 17.0f);

    // 4 - Set padding for plot area
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:1.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:1.0f];

    // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
}

-(void)configurePlotsThree {
    // 1 - Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    // 2 - Create the plots
    CPTScatterPlot *tremorPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    tremorPlot.dataSource = self;
    tremorPlot.identifier = tremorSCORE;
    CPTColor *tremorColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    [graph addPlot:tremorPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    // 3 - Set up plot space
    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tremorPlot,  nil]];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

    // 4 - Create styles and symbols
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tremorLineStyle = [tremorPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    tremorLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    tremorLineStyle.lineColor = tremorColor;
    tremorPlot.dataLineStyle = tremorLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tremorSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tremorSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = tremorColor;}

-(void)configureAxesThree {
    // 1 - Create styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 10.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = .01f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 9.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    // 2 - Get axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    // 3 - Configure x-axis
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.title = @"";
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    x.titleOffset = 20.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
    x.labelRotation = .6;
    x.labelOffset = 15;

    CGFloat dateCount = [self.dates count];
    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (NSString *date in self.dates) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i++;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;

        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
        }
    }
    x.axisLabels = xLabels;
    x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;

    //    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:15.0];   // 8-22

    // 4 - Configure y-axis
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title = @"";
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = -40.0f;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = nil;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.labelTextStyle = nil;
    y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
    y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 1.0f;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    NSInteger majorIncrement = 2;
    NSInteger minorIncrement = 1;
    CGFloat yMax = 700.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }
    y.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`labelRotation`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/group__axis_animation.html#ga4db159f7fc3eeb6e051673ede30c6ebe) on the x-axis to rotate the labels when using one of the automatic labelling policies. When creating custom labels, you need to set the [`rotation`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_axis_label.html#a8c91e79fe74881cd0a1c7cf7e20b6182) on each label directly.

Comment: Thanks, I have set to this  x.labelRotation = .25; and several other values but the labels on the x axis are still showing horizontal. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add your code to the question so we can see the details. Keep in mind the angle measurement is in radians.

Comment: Please see my code for this section above in my original question. Thanks for your help

Comment: I edited my answer with more information about custom labels.

Comment: Now it all makes sense and works perfectly ;) Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, I've almost got this working. It's plotting vertical, but the label is upside down. Is there any way to flip the label 180?  I've a few things to no avail. Thanks

Comment: Add π to the label rotation to flip it. Rotations are measured in radians.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.